# Angular 2 with TypeScript: View not updating after setting variable in response handler

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I ran into an issue with Angular 2 using TypeScript that I could use an extra set of eyes on. I am requesting a token from an API which works great. In my response handler I am checking for basic errors and displaying them to the end users. If I log out the error and my message from the console it displays correctly but the view/template does not update.

**In my class I have the following:**

```
public message: string;
```

**In my constructor I have:**

```
constructor() {
    this.message = 'Message to enduser';
}
```

**My two methods are the following:**

```
myRequest() {
    (<any>window).privateAPI.getToken({
        token: this.tmpData.token
    }, this.responseHandler);
    return false;
}

responseHandler(response: any) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (response.error) {
            // this.message update is not updating in the template
            this.message = response.error.message;
            console.log('error: ', this.message);
        } else {
            // success
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

**Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by utilizing ngZone. The following resolves my problem with my component not updating my template in the API response.

```
// import NgZone
import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

// pass NgZone to constructor
constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {
    this.message = 'Message to enduser';
}


requestToken() {
    (<any>window).privateAPI.getToken({
    token: this.tmpData.token
    }, (status: number, response: any) => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
            if (response.error) {
                this.message = response.error.message;
            } else {
              // good to go
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you created a new context within `setTimeout`. The keyword `function` does this automatically. In TypeScript you can use [lambdas](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) (under Lambdas and using this), also called [arrow-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions). When using a lambda, it *will automatically capture the this available when the function is created rather than when it is invoked*.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if (response.error) {
        // this.message update is not updating in the template
        this.message = response.error.message;
        console.log('error: ', this.message);
    } else {
        // success
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: That was my initial thought (Hoisting) but when I tried that this.message  resulted in undefined Cannot set property 'message' of undefined

Comment: You mean to say `this` is undefined there? I don't know with which context `responseHandler` has been called from the privateAPI callback...

Comment: Yes this in the setTimeout(() => { in the if condition

Comment: Thanks Kaj looks like the issue is in the privateAPI callback

Comment: use this.responseHandler.bind(this) to make sure the context is right.

Comment: Shlomi unfortunately that did not work either. I managed to get it to work. I will post the answer momentarily